# For how long the iterator returned by std::set.find() lives?

Tags: c++, stl, set, stdset

I need to keep track of std::set element by saving the iterator returned by set.find().

My questions is does insertion and removing *other* elements invalidates the obtained iterator? From a simple test I did I can see it is not, but I'd like to ensure this feature is by design.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It never invalidates iterators or pointers/references to the elements. Only if you remove the element itself does the iterator or pointer/reference become invalid.

`23.1.2/8`:

> The insert members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the erase members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.