# std::map and behavior of already inserted data

Tags: c++, stl

Does `std::map` move around already inserted **values** when inserting new data ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The map is implemented as a tree, and when you insert a new element, the tree may need to be rebalanced.

This does *not* invalidate any iterators or references to elements in the tree. This balancing is done via the manipulation of pointers, so you have nothing to worry about; the nodes themselves stay put.

Balancing involves changing the structure of the tree by telling nodes who their children, parents, and siblings are via re-assigning pointers, but this is an implementation detail. Logically nothing has changed.

Comment: I'm wondering, if `it` is an iterator to an element, then before and after an insertion `*it` refers to the same map entry but is it guaranteed that `&*it` remains the same?  In most implementations I would expect this to be true, but it would be possible to implement an iterator with sufficient proxying that the elements could move around but the iterators retain consistency.

Comment: @Charles 23.1.2/8 also states that no references to the container are invalidated.

Comment: @Charles: Good question, I never thought about it. Thanks @Andreas for the answer.

Comment: @Charles, iterators point to nodes. The actual position of the node in the tree is irrelevant. *Values* reside in the nodes. So `&*it` won't change, unless you're fearless and remove the node during the iteration.

Comment: @Nick: Iterators only *represent* pointers; how they manage to do that doesn't necessarily have to be by pointer. Like Charles mentioned, it could be possible to achieve this by a proxy, allowing elements to change position.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks for the reference; I was fairly sure that there was such a restriction but had a moment of doubt when I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Charles: maybe the wording of the answer is not clear enough: nodes will NOT be moved. The shape of the balanced tree (logical structure) will change, but elements will never be reseated in a different part of memory. Each node is created in a position in memory, and that will never change. When the tree is rebalanced the values of the left, right and parent pointers will change to point to different nodes, but the node itself will still be in the same memory address, although in a different path from the root of the tree.

Comment: @Charles taken care of by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068557/c-storing-references-to-values-in-stdmap/1069200#1069200 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364662/for-how-long-the-iterator-returned-by-stdset-find-lives/2364680#2364680 have fun :)

Comment: There is one question however in the iterator invalidation trick: I am not sure that `end` is guaranteed to remain the same when insertion or removal are done... I am not sure that there is any guarantee on this part from the standard.

Comment: I guess that the answer is actually misleading: 'Inserting may move nodes around as an implementation detail, but logically nothing has changed.' If the memory could be moved then the guarantee that @Andreas pointed from 23.1.2/8 could not be fulfilled by that implementation.

Comment: @David: I did in fact use terrible wording, it's my forté. I meant exactly what you said. In fact, I'm going to steal it now.

Comment: @Matthieu, interesting issue. Maybe that `end` issue is why it says "iterators to the container" instead of "iterators to the elements"? Contrast this to `23.1/11` which uses a different wording for the general case.

Answer (score 2):

The standard does not mandate specific implementations of the STL, only the behavior and runtime characteristics. That said, a skip list or tree is a very likely implementation of std::map, so links will be updated, and the relative ordering will change, but the actual data is not going to be moving around.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a typical node in doubly linked list:

```
template <class T>
struct Node
{
  Node* mPrevious;
  Node* mNext;
  T mValue;
};
```

When inserting a new node between two existing ones, all you have to do is some rewiring.

```
void insert(Node* target, Node* newNode)
{
  target->mPrevious->mNext = newNode;
  target->mPrevious = newNode;

  newNode->mPrevious = target->mPrevious;
  newNode->mNext = target;
}
```

The behavior is similar with an `std::map` (or `std::set`, `std::multimap` or `std::multiset` since they are all implemented using the same underlying structure in general).

It means that any iterator pointing to an existing element remains valid too. I do insist on the *existing element* bit. The iterator returned by `end` should be recomputed after insertion or removal and is better not cached.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard does not dictate the implementation of `std::map` only its behavior and efficiency.  Implementations are allowed to move items around; however, this may be inefficient.

Most `std::map` containers are implemented using a tree data structure with links.  When inserting or reordering items, the links are changed, but the data is not moved.  Moving items would slow the execution time of the `std::map`.